# Control angular directive from outside

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make changes to a directive from my main controller.

this is the directive code

```
# directive.coffee
application.directive 'btnState', ->
    {
        restrict: 'A'
        link: (scope, el, attrs) ->
            attrs.$observe 'ngModel', (newVal) ->
                switch newVal
                    when 'loading'
                        # do something
                    when 'reset'
                        # do other thing
            el.click (event) ->
                attrs.$set 'ngModel', 'loading'
            return
    }
```

now in my template

```
<button id="#do-btn" ng-click="doSometing()" ng-model="ns.btn_state" btn-state>Do it</button>
<button id="#cancel-btn" ng-click="ns.btn_state = 'reset'">Cancel</button>
```

When i click on `#do-btn` button works fine the `$observe` catch the change but when i try to change the `ns.btn_state` from outside is never catched

How i can solve this?

I'm using angular 1.0.7

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, `attrs.$observe` and `attrs.$set` are used to manipulate the *value* of a given attribute, not the *content*.

If you care about the *content* you should use [`$watch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) and [`$parse`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse) over the *value* of your attributes.

For instance in

```
<input ng-model="foo" />
```

with

```
$scope.foo = "bar";
```

the *value* of the attribute `'ngModel'` is `"foo"` and its content is `"bar"`.

In the case you don't expect the *value* of your attribute to change, i.e. it is not interpolated, in order to read/write the *content* of the model it's representing you could just do

```
var model = $parse(attrs.foo);
var content = model(scope); // read
scope.$apply(function () {
  model.assign(scope, 'new content'); // write
});
```

And to *react* to changes

```
scope.$watch(attrs.foo, function (new, old) { ... });
```

If your attribute is interpolated, then you should `$observe` it before watching and parsing it, but seems to be a very complicated use-case.

Comment: in a `scope.$watch` version how i can change the value inside the directive

Comment: I also wrapped the `assign` into an `$apply` to make it clearer.

Comment: where it comes from `$parse`?

Comment: It's an Angular service. You can get it from your directive through usual injection. The doc is here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$parse.